# Proving continuity of (xy)^(1/3)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

Let $f(x,y)= (xy)^{\frac13}$

How would you prove that f is continous at the origin using Eplison delta argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$ and we look for $\delta>0$ such that $|xy|^{1/3}<\epsilon$ whenever $||(x,y)||=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta$. Notice that
$$|xy|^{1/3}<\epsilon\iff|xy|<\epsilon ^3\Leftarrow |x|,|y|<\epsilon^{3/2}\Leftarrow||(x,y)||<\epsilon^{3/2}$$
so it suffices to take $\delta=\epsilon^{3/2}$ and we have:
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)=0=f(0,0)$$
and then $f$ is continuous at the origin.

Comment: This certainly deserves an upvote, Sami!